# Google App Engine generate Endpoint class in IntelliJ

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints

I understand you can generate Endpoint class in Eclipse

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addentities

It there similar way to do it in IntelliJ or you have to do it manually, if so how?

Comment: It seems like possible on the Android Studio, but not on standard IntelliJ edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [this project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-java-maven/blob/master/pom.xml)'s maven build file (pom.xml) and see that it has the appengine plugin installed into it. This makes it so you don't have to install the UI plugin into Android Studio or Eclipse but you get the same AppEngine SDK functionality via maven dependencies.

You'll also need the nbactions.xml file defined in that project as well as src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml files defined similar to the github project. After you configure these files then Cloud Endpoints should work and you should be able to run 'mvn install appengine:devserver' or invoke the same goal from Eclipse or IntelliJ UIs.

Upon successful deployment `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer` will get you to the API explorer.

Comment: The goal to generate your client lib for java would be appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib